# ADO.NET select a row from datagrid1 for show rows in datagrid2

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net, datagridview

So i have problem. I have a SQL server with DB and 2 tables:

```
1-|id|name|,
2-|id|id_id|name|;
id->id_id has a conection.
```

I connected SQL to VS like a DataSource.

I have 3 forms in VS(C#): MainForm(for select forms with DataGridView's), form with DGV1 and form with DGV2.

So first open MainForm, next by button form with DGV1. I can add, delete and change rows, but i need do button for select row(need select id or get his value), next close form DGV1. 
Next open form DGV2 by button on MainForm and at the time of opennig need do query for DGV2 like a:

```
SELECT id, id_id, name FROM TABLE WHERE (id_id = selected id from DGV1)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you want to select info from the second table for a given id_id.

If so, you have to save the id from DG1 somewhere and then select the data like this:

```
select id, id_id, name
FROM TABLE
WHERE id_id = @idDG1
```

where @idDG1 must be the value itself. If you select id 1 from DG1 the query must be:

```
select id, id_id, name
FROM TABLE
WHERE id_id = 1
```

and so on.

---

One final note, you can use @idDG1 and add a parameter when building the query.

Comment: Yes, but how to get value by button? Copy between the forms? And copy this value in querry?

Comment: @Johnny yes! Check this out: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/75208-passing-data-between-forms-in-c%23/

Comment: @Johnny if you don't select a row and then for that row you select the data, how can you select the data without the row selected?

Comment: @Johnny I'll check in home later on. Now I'm at work and can't access that link.